# Subscribe click event without eventhandler and use custom arguments

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

I want to make the click of a context menu item do something, so I would do:

```
cmsItemOne.Click += new EventHandler(someFunction);
```

However, I have a function that only needs custom arguments to be passed in:

```
private void customFunction(string someText, int someNumber)
```

So how can I subscribe `cmsItemOne.Click` to `customFunction` and pass in the arguments.
For example, (doesn't work)

```
string theString = "Hello world";
int theInt = 5;

cmsItemOne.Click += customFunction(theString, theInt);
```

Comment: you can declare a standard `someFunction` which calls `customFunction`.

Comment: But how would I get the arguments passed into `someFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)`?

Comment: See codeproject.  Used this code last week in one of my projects : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a closure

```
string theString = "Hello world";
int theInt = 5;

cmsItemOne.Click += (s,e) => customFunction(theString, theInt);
```

[How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events)

Comment: I've tried this, but the function is never being run, I put a `MessageBox.Show("ran custom function");` in customFunction as well to verify it definitely isn't being executed.

Comment: Then that event is not raised. See the link I added to the answer with an official How-To guide

Comment: You're right, my mistake, I forgot I was using a testing context menu item and I never switched it to the proper one. Thanks.

Comment: @SirRufo - It would be nice to show how to detach a lambda too.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the event handler method call that function with multiple argument.

```
cmsItemOne.Click += new EventHandler(someFunction);

private void buttonGenTool_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customFunction(someText, someNumber);
}

private void customFunction(string someText, int someNumber)
{
    //Your function code;
}
```

Comment: How do I pass in the arguments (variables) in `someFunction` to use them as `someText` and `someNumber`?

Comment: @Kamdroid global values

Comment: @LeiYang - There are no global values in C#.

Comment: static then? what ever you call